# Filter RadGridTemplateColumn contains RadGridList

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

I have a Telerik Grid contains a template column, this column holds a `RadGridList` and receives its data from StringCollection, this means that I have a column with multiple values.

I'm trying to filter this column using a combobox, I can filter such columns but with only single data, but how to filter a column contains multiple data represented by `StringCollection`?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use the `Contains` function as your `CurrentFilterFunction` instead of `EqualTo`.

Read more about [GridKnownFunctions](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/t_telerik_web_ui_gridknownfunction.html).